Which TV series featured children on a tropical island stopping criminals?
I am trying to remember a TV series from my youth in the UK (approximately 1990-1995). 
It featured a band of children, somewhat attached to a hotel, on a tropical island.  They would prevent crime and solve mysteries often aided by a taxi driver IRC with a strong Jamaican accent.   The location may have been a fictional Caribbean location or real (Trinidad etc).  
The show was not Ship to Shore which I remember.
The theme tune reminded me vaguely of the Madonna hit La Isla Bonita. 

I think you're on the right track with an Aussie show, though. They made a whole bunch of kids shows on islands in the 80s and early 90s.

I think you're after Runaway Bay (1992-1993) which aired on ITV, about a bunch of kids solving crimes in a hotel (that I'm almost sure belonged to the parents of one of them) on a Caribbean island. It also featured Naomie Harris in one of her earliest roles. Here's the intro (in which some of the music might sound like La Isla Bonita, I guess) and a few minutes:




That is it!! How did you find it?  :-)

Looked for kids shows on islands. The premise sounded familiar, but I don't think I know Runaway Bay, so I must've remembered some other show. Glad you found it. :)

Looks like an appearance for Joseph Marcell too before he went on to Fresh Prince fame.

Could it be The Castle of Adventure 
Plot Summary:

Jack, Lucy, Dinah and Philip attempt to figure out what is behind the
  strange goings-on at a ruined castle near Spring Cottage in Scotland
  where they are on holiday with Dinah and Philip's mother, Aunt Allie.
  The four youngsters make friends with Tassie, a mysterious gypsy
  living in the woods with her mother. Along with Bill Cunningham, who
  appears later in the book, the children manage to expose a ring of
  spies led by the threatening Scar-Neck who are working against the UK
  Military service


No, unfortunately not although that series does look interesting.

"fictional Caribbean location or real" - Scotland? Not sure where that came from (as someone who lives in Scotland and is currently got the central heating on at the end of June).

It is a movie for god Sake
